# Windows Phone: IsolatedStorageSettings in class library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to create helper library for Windows Phone. So, I've created class library project, and I want to write helpers for `IsolatedStorageSettings`. But class library can find only `IsolatedStorageFile`. Is there a way to work with `IsolatedStorageSettings` from class library? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference System.Windows.dll, where [IsolatedStorageSettings is defined.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(v=vs.105).aspx)

Whenever you need to use a class in the framework and you don't know where it is, simply go to the docs and look at the top...

> Inheritance Hierarchy
>   System.Object
>    System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings
>   Namespace:  System.IO.IsolatedStorage
>   **Assembly:  System.Windows (in System.Windows.dll)**